# TransactionException: Cannot unmarshal invalid hex string when deploying contract in web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3j, java

I have a java server that uses web3j library with geth as the provider. When I tried to deploy my contract on my private test net. I got this error:

```
org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction 0x70fed47c9d291f0818ff239be085b2dc3a87f436f56b9c0b6750e568a24dbdf1 has failed with status: 0x0. Gas used: 6721975. Revert reason: 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal invalid hex string into Go struct field CallArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes'.
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:377)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.create(Contract.java:422)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:456)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:506)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$5(Contract.java:549)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:42)
    at java_ethereum.ContractController.deployContract(ContractController.java:41)
```

My java code looks something like this:

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://localhost:8545"));
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("", "path/to/geth/keystore");
String contractAddress = deployContract(web3, credentials);
MyContract myContract = loadContract(contractAddress, web3, credentials);
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String deployContract(Web3j web3, Credentials credentials) throws Exception{
        return myContract.deploy(web3, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT).send().getContractAddress();
    }
```

My web3j should be the latest version(4.8.4), I am not sure if I have missed anything. The content of the contract should not matter (I think) because the same error pops up even when I try to deploy a blank contract.
I suspect there is some problem with the credentials created from geth. Any help would be appreciated.

My command to initialize the geth node:

```
geth  --identity "TestNode" --rpc -rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"  --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" --nodiscover  --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,miner,net,personal,net,txpool,debug,admin"  --networkid 1900    --datadir C:/Users/Documents/Test --allow-insecure-unlock  --ipcdisable   --dev --dev.period 1
```

@Majd TL suggests testing it on ganache instead, and it returns different error this time:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:460)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:506)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$5(Contract.java:549)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:42)
    at ContractController.deployContract(ContractController.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:162)
    at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:127)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:367)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.create(Contract.java:422)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:456)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: if you upload the project on github with the smart contract, I could probably help more (using ganache). but take care remove any private infomration

Comment: @MajdTL Well here you go [link](https://github.com/kinson603/Web3j-test-and-debug). Feel free to test it. I think I have removed any sensitive information.

Comment: I tested it... and i got another problem... :( I will take another try at the weekend

Comment: @MajdTL Any luck? I mean ganache does show that a block is mined from contract creation even though the error pops up.

Comment: yes I saw the contract on ganache, but could not solve the error,# maybe there is something wrong with that web3 maven version, or your java application. try to use java 11

Comment: I've figured out what's the problem... Web3j CLI doesn't accept the binary from Remix-IDE

Comment: Okay didn’t knew that, great :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what's going on.

Referring to this post [Web3j gets stack underflow error with Ganache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581930/web3j-gets-stack-underflow-error-with-ganache/60598228#60598228), turns out that  Web3j CLI doesn't accept and process properly for any binary file generated from Remix-IDE (Don't know why but definitely a bug).

So I switched the IDE to Buidl to compile and it works perfectly now on both ganache and geth.

Answer (score 0):

As another way of doing it. If you have the smart contract, you can actually use the [web3j-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-gradle-plugin) to compile the contract on the go and deploy it (without having to copy past manually the generated java wrapper).

To do so, just apply the plugin to your project using:

```
plugins {
  id "org.web3j" version "4.8.4"
}
```

if you are using gradle. If not, you can also specify it for a maven project.

Then, put the smart contract under the `src/main/solidity` folder and it will be picked up automatically, compiled and the java wrappers will be generated and also available to use directly from your code.